# Remove utm_source parameter and replace index with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

what I am trying to do is delete the `utm_source` parameter and after that replace any request with my `index2.html` file.

This is what I tried:

```
# BEGIN
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "utm" [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ "index2.html$1" [QSA,L]
RewriteRule (.*) /$1? [R=301,L,QSD]
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# END
```

With this line of code I delete the `utm_source` parameter:

```
RewriteRule (.*) /$1? [R=301,L,QSD]
```

What I want is to use this line of code `RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ "index2.html$1" [QSA,L]` and then delete the `utm_source` parameter but I have not been able to do it.

Worse so far I have only managed to do one thing at a time. If you delete the parameter, do not do the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `.htaccess` file is in the document root...

To delete just the `utm_source` URL parameter (and not *all* parameters) you can do something like the following first:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)&?utm_source=[^&]*&?(.*)$
RewriteRule (.*) /$1?%1%2 [R=302,L]
```

Then, to rewrite all requests to `index2.html` you would do something like the following (assuming you don't want to also rewrite requests for existing files):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) index2.html [L]
```

However, in your directive you are not simply rewriting to `index2.html`, you are also attempting to append additional pathname information (path-info) - is this required? Although in your code you are missing a slash (when used in `.htaccess`), so the rewrite would be malformed and result in a 404. If you needed path-info then change the last `RewriteRule` to:

```
RewriteRule (.*) index2.html/$1 [L]
```

#### Summary

```
RewriteEngine On

# Remove the "utm_source" URL parameter
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)&?utm_source=[^&]*&?(.*)$
RewriteRule (.*) /$1?%1%2 [R=302,L]

# Rewrite all requests to "index2.html"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) index2.html [L]
```

No need for the `<IfModule>` wrapper, since your code presumably won't work without mod_rewrite? Also no need for the `RewriteBase` directive if your `.htaccess` file is in the document root.

---

> ```
> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "utm" [NC]
> RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ "index2.html$1" [QSA,L]
> RewriteRule (.*) /$1? [R=301,L,QSD]
> ```

There are a number of issues with your current directives. A couple that stand out...

- The rules are in the wrong order, since the condition that checks the query string only applies to the first `RewriteRule` that follows. Consequently, the last `RewriteRule` (that you say "removes the utm_source parameter) executes unconditionally and would result in a redirect loop.
- The first rule (that rewrites to `index2.html$1`) would only execute if "utm" was present (anywhere) in the query string (it is not removed). But `index2.html$1` would result in an invalid rewrite in `.htaccess` (as mentioned above - you are missing a slash).
- Your last rule removes the entire query string, not just the `utm_source` parameter. Yet your first rule tries to append a query string to the rewritten request.